# Smaller pointers... possible? (without a lower spec system)

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, cuda

In this 2010 [paper](http://www.tml.tkk.fi/~samuli/publications/laine2010i3d_paper.pdf)<sup>[1]</sup> on raycasting sparse voxel octrees (SVOs) (apologies; the paper takes a while to load), section 3 indicates an interesting memory setup to save space on voxel data, which almost invariably is very large.

They specify a 15-bit relative pointer, with a 1-bit flag to specify whether a far pointer is needed (if the volume data is too large, the flag is set, and the 15-bit pointer is considered to point to a secondary, far pointer).

What's being done to achieve this? Is this something to do with CUDA / the GPU? Is it done through a custom allocator of some sort, in C++ code?

How would this be done in C++, if at all?

<sup>[1]</sup><sub>Efficient Sparse Voxel Octrees: Samuli Laine, Tero Karras; NVIDIA Research</sub>

Comment: The PDF isn't working for me, but I'm guessing it's just indices of an array. Write a heap allocator to work on the array and you're set.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, you can always manually store the memory in an array and use integer indexes as "pointers".

Comment: Very much this.  Practically speaking, this sort of relative pointer *is* an array index.

Answer (score 8):

In C/C++ you can interpret numbers as pointers in any way that you like - but it means that you wouldn't be able to simply dereference / add / subtract and do other normal pointer things . Instead you would have to use functions converting to a 'true' pointer to do these sorts of operations.

In C++ you could wrap all this up very neatly inside a class that presents a pointer-like interface by implementing `operator*`, `opeartor->`, and the arithmetic operators.

Just based on glancing at figure 2, this is what an implementation of the proposed pointers might look like (note that if you actually do this, then you're going to want to make sure the class isn't padded out to 32 or 64 bits anyway, and that they are allocated on 2-byte boundaries - there are normally compiler-specific directives to control this.)

```
class SmallChildPointer{
    public:
        SmallChildPointer(Child* bigChildPointer)
            : value(){
            ptrdiff_t offset = bigChildPointer - base_address;
            if(offset > 0x7fff)
                throw std::runtime_error("too big for a near pointer...");
            value = uint16_t(offset & 0x7fff);
        }

        Child* operator->() const{
            return (Child*)(base_address + value);
        }

        Child const& operator*() const{
            return *(Child const*)(base_address + value);
        }

        Child& operator*(){
            return *(Child*)(base_address + value);
        }

        // do this once, before constructing any of these!
        static void setTheGlobalBaseAddress(void* here){
             base_address = here;
        }

    private:
        uint16_t value;
        static void* base_address;
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Have you noticed that each of the standard containers takes an allocator template?  It's so that you can implement strange memory models, such as that like you describe. (Or data that's on another computer over the network, or dynamically calculated...) Yes, the best way to do that is with a custom allocator.

```
template<class T>
class linear_allocator  {
public:
    typedef T* pointer;
    typedef const T* const_pointer;
    typedef T& reference;
    typedef T&& r_reference;
    typedef const T& const_reference;
    typedef T value_type;
    template<class _Other>
    struct rebind {
        typedef linear_allocator<_Other> other;
    };

    linear_allocatorr();
    linear_allocator(const linear_allocator<T>& b);
    linear_allocator(linear_allocator<T>&& b);
    template<class U>
    linear_allocator(const linear_allocator<U>& b);
    ~linear_allocator() throw();
    linear_allocator_base& operator=(const linear_allocator_base& b);
    pointer allocate(size_type count=1, pointer hint=nullptr);
    void deallocate(pointer ptr, size_type count=1) throw();
    static size_type max_size() throw();
    bool operator==(const linear_allocator_base& b) const throw();
    bool operator!=(const linear_allocator_base& b) const throw();
    static void construct(pointer ptr);
    static void construct(pointer ptr, const reference val);
    static void construct(pointer ptr, const r_reference val);
    template<class other>
    static void construct(pointer ptr, const other& val);
    template<class other>
    static void construct(pointer ptr, other&& val);
    //template<class ...Args>
    //static void construct(pointer ptr, Args args);
    static void destroy(pointer ptr);
    static pointer address(reference val) throw();
    static const_pointer address(const_reference val) throw();
    static linear_allocator<T> select_on_container_copy_construction();
    typedef std::false_type propagate_on_container_copy_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_move_assignment;
    typedef std::true_type propagate_on_container_swap;
};
```

I did fail to note that the custom pointer (like Autopulated has) is the most important part.  A custom allocator simply lets you use the standard containers/algorithms/etc with those pointers.

Comment: Interesting, I did wonder about allocators. Any recommended sources on getting to grips with this?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d6td8khx(v=VS.71).aspx  It's not actually as complicated as it looks.  Most of those functions are simple one-liners.

Answer (score 0):

An additional option: I found a library with templates on Github that allocates from a static pool and can go as low as 1 byte.

The [library's name is "Small pointer"](https://github.com/HDembinski/small_pointer) and the contributor's alias is HDembinski.